# Comparing list of directories to list in a file and writing another file for comparison

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory, filesystems

I'm stumped on this. As part of bash script, I get given a text file called IDENTIFIERS.TXT that contains a list of directories like this:

```
a_SomeDirectory
b_AnotherOne
c_YetAnother
```

And so on.

What I want to do is to check the IDENTIFIERS.TXT list against the output of `ls` or something for the local contents of `./ItsInHere/` to see which directories on the list exist locally in that path and which do not, as I need that output to build *another* list of directories that do not exist locally to a new text file called INDENTIFIERS_GET.TXT for the next part of the bash script.

For example:

If `a_SomeDirectory` and `b_AnotherOne` exists in `./ItsInHere/` but `c_YetAnother` **doesn't**, I'd need `c_YetAnother` to be written to INDENTIFIERS_GET.TXT and then so on to the next.

I can see this kind of operation may need some crazy piping or something, or perhaps there's even a special command for this... Some kind of mix of `ls` and `sort`? I don't know. Any help?

Many thanks!

Comment: #!/bin/bash
list=`cat list.txt`
for item in $list 
do
        if [ ! -d $item ]; then
                echo $item >> not_exist.txt
        fi
done

Comment: Just do something like this:   `ls ./ItsInHere/ | diff IDENTIFIERS.TXT - > IDENTIFIERS_GET.TXT`